# 2D Array Operations

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am having difficulty figuring out why my methods `getLowestInRow` and `getHighestInRow` seem to be skipping the second column.  I've got a nested for loop iterating over the 2D array, but my output for `getLowestInRow` is not correct, e.g. for row 4 it tells me that 66 is the lowest, where 54 is actually the lowest.

```
...

  int[][] testData={{3, 5, 7}, {33, 44, 12}, {1, 45, 67}, {66, 54, 99}};


...

 /* method getHighestInRow  
   takes a 2d int array, the 
   number of rows and the number 
   of columns as input and
   prints the highest number
   of all of the elements 
   in each individual row of
   the array as (int) outputs 
 */  

 public static int getHighestInRow (int[][] x, int rowCount, int colCount)
 {
     int highestInRow = x[0][0];

     for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
     {
       for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
       {
       highestInRow = x[rowIndex][0];
       if (x[rowIndex][colIndex]>highestInRow)
             highestInRow=x[rowIndex][colIndex];
       }
     System.out.println(highestInRow + " is the highest number in row " + (rowIndex+1) + ".");
     highestInRow = 0;
     }
     return highestInRow;
 }

/* method getLowestInRow
   takes a 2d int array as input 
   returns the lowest number
   of all of the elements 
   in each individual row of
   the array as (int) outputs 
 */  

//unfinished
public static int getLowestInRow (int[][] x, int rowCount, int colCount)
{
     int lowestInRow = x[0][0];

     for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
     {
       for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
       {
       lowestInRow = x[rowIndex][0];  
       if (x[rowIndex][colIndex]<lowestInRow)
             lowestInRow=x[rowIndex][colIndex];
       }
     System.out.println(lowestInRow + " is the lowest number in row " + (rowIndex+1) + ".");       
     lowestInRow = 0;
     }
    return lowestInRow;

}

...
```

Comment: Always try to post only relevant code.

Comment: Please can you cut down your code to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the same problem ? You say that it's the `getLowestInRow` where the problem is; it's not helpful to show all of the other methods too.

Comment: Why are you calling the method `getLowestInRow` if it actually is supposed to return the lowest in all the array? It's hard to tell where the problem is when your described expectation doesn't match the description of the method.

Comment: thanks, i have reduced it down to the offending methods.  sorry for the confusion.  it's supposed to return the highest or lowest in each row in the array, i think it does say that in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the highest and lowest function as below:-

```
 public static int getHighestInRow (int[][] x, int rowCount, int colCount)
     {
         int highestInRow = 0;

         for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
         {
             highestInRow = x[rowIndex][0];
           for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
           {

           if (x[rowIndex][colIndex]>highestInRow)
                 highestInRow=x[rowIndex][colIndex];
           }
         System.out.println(highestInRow + " is the highest number in row " + (rowIndex+1) + ".");
         highestInRow = 0;
         }
         return highestInRow;
     }

    /* method getLowestInRow
       takes a 2d int array as input 
       returns the lowest number
       of all of the elements 
       in each individual row of
       the array as (int) outputs 
     */  

    //unfinished
    public static int getLowestInRow (int[][] x, int rowCount, int colCount)
    {
         int lowestInRow = 0;

         for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
         {
             lowestInRow = x[rowIndex][0];  
           for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
           {

           if (x[rowIndex][colIndex]<lowestInRow)
                 lowestInRow=x[rowIndex][colIndex];
           }
         System.out.println(lowestInRow + " is the lowest number in row " + (rowIndex+1) + ".");       
         lowestInRow = 0;
         }
        return lowestInRow;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've commented the lines of code not required in your code. Hope this helps you.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] testData={{3, 5, 7}, {33, 44, 12}, {1, 45, 67}, {66, 54, 99}};

    int rowCount = testData.length;
    int colCount = getNumCols(testData);

/*      getTotal(testData, rowCount, colCount);
    getAverage(testData, rowCount, colCount);
    getRowTotal(testData, rowCount, colCount);
    getColumnTotal(testData, rowCount, colCount);*/
    getHighestInRow(testData, rowCount, colCount);
    getLowestInRow(testData, rowCount, colCount);
}

/* method getTotal
   takes a 2d int array as input 
   returns a sum of all elements of 
   the array as (int) output 
*/  

public static int getTotal(int[][] x, int rowCount, int colCount)
{
    int total = 0; 
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
    {
         for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
         {
             total += x[rowIndex][colIndex];   
         }
    }   
    System.out.println("The total is "+ total);
    return total;
}

/* method getAverage
   takes a 2d int array as input 
   returns the average of all elements 
   of the array as (int) output 
*/  

public static double getAverage(int[][] x, int rowCount, int colCount)
{
    int total = 0; 
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
    {
         for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
         {
             total += x[rowIndex][colIndex];   
         }
    }     
    double average = (total/(colCount*rowCount));
    System.out.println("The average is "+average);
    return average; 
 }

/* method getRowTotal
   takes a 2d int array as input 
   returns the total of all elements 
   in each individual row of
   the array as (int) outputs 
*/ 

public static int getRowTotal(int[][] x, int rowCount, int colCount)
{
    int rowTotal = 0; 
    int rowIndex = 0;
    for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
        {
            rowTotal += x [rowIndex][colIndex];      
        }
        System.out.println("The total for row " + (rowIndex+1) + " is " + rowTotal);
        rowTotal = 0;
    }   
    return rowTotal;
}


/* method getColumnTotal
   takes a 2d int array as input 
   returns the total of all elements 
   in each individual column of
   the array as (int) outputs 
*/  

//unfinished    
public static int getColumnTotal(int[][] x, int rowCount, int colCount)
{
    int columnTotal = 0; 
    int rowIndex = 0;
    int colIndex = 0;
    for (colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
    {
        for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
        {             
            columnTotal += x [rowIndex][colIndex];          
        }
        System.out.println("The total for column " + (colIndex+1) + " is " + columnTotal);
        columnTotal = 0;
    }   
    return columnTotal; 
 }

 /* method getHighestInRow  
   takes a 2d int array, the 
   number of rows and the number 
   of columns as input and
   prints the highest number
   of all of the elements 
   in each individual row of
   the array as (int) outputs 
 */  

 public static int getHighestInRow (int[][] x, int rowCount, int colCount)
 {
     int highestInRow = x[0][0];

     for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
     {
       for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
       {
//         highestInRow = x[rowIndex][0];
       if (x[rowIndex][colIndex]>highestInRow)
             highestInRow=x[rowIndex][colIndex];
       }
     System.out.println(highestInRow + " is the highest number in row " + (rowIndex+1) + ".");
     highestInRow = 0;
     }
     return highestInRow;
 }

/* method getLowestInRow
   takes a 2d int array as input 
   returns the lowest number
   of all of the elements 
   in each individual row of
   the array as (int) outputs 
 */  

//unfinished
public static int getLowestInRow (int[][] x, int rowCount, int colCount)
{
     int lowestInRow = x[0][0];

     for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++)
     {
         lowestInRow = x[rowIndex][0];
       for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
       {
//         lowestInRow = x[rowIndex][0];  
       if (x[rowIndex][colIndex]<lowestInRow)
             lowestInRow=x[rowIndex][colIndex];
       }
     System.out.println(lowestInRow + " is the lowest number in row " + (rowIndex+1) + ".");       

     }
    return lowestInRow;

}


public static int getNumCols (int[][] x)
{
    int rowCount = 0;
    int colCount = 0;

    for (rowCount = 0; rowCount < x.length; rowCount++)
    {
        for (colCount = 0; colCount < x[rowCount].length; colCount++)
        {
        }
    }
    return colCount;     
}
```